# Metabase MongoDB - join collections across databases?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, metabase

Is there any way or hack to join two (or more) collections *from different dbs together* in Metabase's native questions?

e.g.

- `DB1` has `pets` collection
- `DB2` has `owners` collection

It's easy to link collections across dbs through other means (`mongoose`, for example), but having difficulty achieving this via Metabase's native questions.

Tried using `$lookup` operator — either I'm not using it properly, or it doesn't allow reads across dbs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Metabase, but you can't do that directly with `$lookup`, details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74408288/20042973)

Comment: Yeah I saw that...also saw the thing about the "federated database scenario", which I just saw you mentioned in your answer there as well. So weird that there isn't a (straightforward) way to do this already...

Comment: Yeah. Google suggests that it is a long-standing request tracked [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34935)